# Sending selected checkbox via mail, not just first option

Tags: php, ajax, email

I am trying to email a form once its filled out and sent.

Users will be able to fill out the form and receive a result based on the values in the option, the information the user filled out will be emailed to a email account.

When the email is is sent, it only sends the first option within a group, e.g. Within question 1, if option 3 within that group, is clicked it will still send as if option one has been sent.

Any feedback would be really appreciated, just totally stumped on this one...

**Index.php**

```
<div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
      <div class="form-style-heading">Contact Us</div>
      <div id="contact_results"></div>
      <div id="quiz_result"></div>
      <div id="contact_body">

        <div class="page">
          <label>
            <span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" class="input-field"/>
          </label>
          <label>
            <span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="email" name="email" required="true" class="input-field"/>
          </label>
          <label>
            <span>Company <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="text" name="company" required="true" class="input-field"/>
          </label>
          <label>
            <span>Job Title <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="text" name="jobtitle" required="true" class="input-field"/>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="page">
          <legend>1. Question Number 1?</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="question1" class="option" value="100"><label>Answer One</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question1" class="option" value="75"><label>Answer Two</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question1" class="option" value="50"><label>Answer Three</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question1" class="option" value="0"><label>Answer Four</label>
        </div>

        <div class="page">
          <legend>2. Question Number 2?</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="question2" class="option" value="100"><label>Answer One</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question2" class="option" value="75"><label>Answer Two</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question2" class="option" value="50"><label>Answer Three</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question2" class="option" value="0"><label>Answer Four</label>
        </div>

        <div class="page">
          <legend>3. Question Number 3?</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="question3" class="option" value="20"><label>Answer One</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question3" class="option" value="40"><label>Answer Two</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question3" class="option" value="60"><label>Answer Three</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question3" class="option" value="80"><label>Answer Four</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question3" class="option" value="100"><label>Answer Five</label>
        </div>

        <div class="page">
          <legend>4. Question Number 4?</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="question4" class="option" value="100"><label>Yes</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question4" class="option" value="0"><label>No</label>
        </div>

        <div class="page">
          <legend>5. Question Number 5?</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="question5" class="option" value="20"><label>Answer One</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question5" class="option" value="40"><label>Answer Two</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question5" class="option" value="60"><label>Answer Three</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question5" class="option" value="80"><label>Answer Four</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question5" class="option" value="100"><label>Answer Five</label>
        </div>

        <div class="page">
          <legend>6. Question Number 6?</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="question6" class="option" value="100"><label>Answer One</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question6" class="option" value="80"><label>Answer Two</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question6" class="option" value="60"><label>Answer Three</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question6" class="option" value="40"><label>Answer Four</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="question6" class="option" value="20"><label>Answer Five</label>
        </div>

        <label>
          <input type="button" id="next" value="Next" onlick="sum_values()" />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**contact_me.php**

```
if($_POST) {
  $to_email       = "receiver@email.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here
  $from_email     = 'sender@email.com'; //from mail, it is mandatory with some hosts and without it mail might endup in spam.

  //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
  if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
    'type'=>'error',
    'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
  }

  //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
  $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $user_company   = filter_var($_POST["user_company"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $user_job_title = filter_var($_POST["user_job_title"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $question_one = filter_var($_POST["questionOne"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $question_two = filter_var($_POST["questionTwo"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $question_three = filter_var($_POST["questionThree"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $question_four = filter_var($_POST["questionFour"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $question_five = filter_var($_POST["questionFive"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $question_six = filter_var($_POST["questionSix"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  //additional php validation
  if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
    die($output);
  }

  //email body
  $message_body = "Name: ".$user_name."\r\nEmail: ".$user_email."\r\nCompany: ".$user_company."\r\nJob Title: ".$user_job_title."\r\n\n\nQuestion 1: ".$question_one."\r\nQuestion 2: ".$question_two."\r\nQuestion 3: ".$question_three."\r\nQuestion 4: ".$question_four."\r\nQuestion 5: ".$question_five."\r\nQuestion 6: ".$question_six ;

  //proceed with PHP email.
  $headers = 'From: '. $from_email .'' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  $send_mail = mail($to_email, 'Survey Results', $message_body, $headers);

  if(!$send_mail) {
    //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
  }else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
    die($output);
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var totalPages = $('.page').size();

  var currentPage = 0;

  $pages = $('.page');

  $pages.hide();

  $($pages.get(currentPage)).fadeIn();

  $('#next').click(function () {

    $($pages.get(currentPage)).fadeOut(function () {

      currentPage = currentPage + 1;

      if (currentPage == totalPages) {

        var total = 0;
        $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
          total+= parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
        });

        var answerOne = "Result 1";
        var answerTwo = "Result 2";
        var answerThree = "Result 3";
        var answerFour = "Result 4";
        var answerFive = "Result 5";

        if (total < 265) {
          $("#quiz_result").append('<div>' + answerOne + '</div>');
        } else {
          if (total > 266 && total < 355) {
            $("#quiz_result").append('<div>' + answerTwo + '</div>');
          } else {
            if (total > 356 && total < 475) {
              $("#quiz_result").append('<div>' + answerThree + '</div>');
            } else {
              if (total > 476 && total < 560) {
                $("#quiz_result").append('<div>' + answerFour + '</div>');
              } else {
                if (total > 570 && total <= 600) {
                  $("#quiz_result").append('<div>' + answerFive + '</div>');
                } else {
                  $("#quiz_result").append('<div>' + answerOne + '</div>');
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        post_data = {
          'user_name' : $('input[name=name]').val(),
          'user_email' : $('input[name=email]').val(),
          'user_company' : $('input[name=company]').val(),
          'user_job_title' : $('input[name=jobtitle]').val(),

          'questionOne' : $('input[name=question1]').val(),
          'questionTwo' : $('input[name=question2]').val(),
          'questionThree' : $('input[name=question3]').val(),
          'questionFour' : $('input[name=question4]').val(),
          'questionFive' : $('input[name=question5]').val(),
          'questionSix' : $('input[name=question6]').val(),
        };

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){
          if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message
            output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
          }else{
            output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
            //reset values in all input fields
            $("#contact_form  input[required=true]").val('');
            $("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
          }
          $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

        $('#next').hide();

      } else {

        //otherwise show the next question
        $($pages.get(currentPage)).fadeIn();

      }

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: is it just me or there is no checkbox?

Comment: Ah, I meant Options. Not Checkboxes, I will update. Sorry!

Comment: "sending the first option in that group" - huh?. Please structure this question a bit better.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated this, all I mean is that when sending an email it will always send the email as if option 1 within a group has been sent. I believe the problem is that all options in a group have the same "name" attribute (e.g. question1, question2 etc.) but cannot work how to send the checked option when sending an email